# Unicode version of base64 encoding/ decoding

Tags: c++, base64

I am using base64 encoding/decoding from http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

It works pretty well with the following code.

```
  const std::string s = "I Am A Big Fat Cat" ;

  std::string encoded = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()), s.length());
  std::string decoded = base64_decode(encoded);

  std::cout << _T("encoded: ") << encoded << std::endl;
  std::cout << _T("decoded: ") << decoded << std::endl;
```

However, when comes to unicode

```
namespace std
{
#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef wstring tstring;
#else
    typedef string tstring;
#endif
}
const std::tstring s = _T("I Am A Big Fat Cat");
```

How can I still make use of the above function?

Merely changing

```
std::string base64_encode(unsigned TCHAR const* , unsigned int len);
std::tstring base64_decode(std::string const& s);
```

will not work correctly.

(I expect base64_encode to return ASCII. Hence, std::string should be used instead of std::tstring)

Comment: have you tried another encoder?  this one give `std::string`  http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/src/modp_b64.h

Comment: What are the symptoms of your "merely changing" not working? I might expect the string to be truncated because the length is specified in characters instead of bytes, but otherwise it should be OK.

Comment: You aren't supposed to add things to the `std` namespace.

Comment: By supporting Unicode, do you mean that you want to base64-encode wstrings (L"ABC" → "QUJD"), or that you want to base64-encode TO wstrings ("ABC" → L"QUJD")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base64 encodes binary data as text. So you'll just need to convert your wide chars into their corresponding bytes using [wcstombs & co](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and you're good to go.

Comment: You'll have to be careful when it comes to defining "their corresponding bytes". Given the `_UNICODE` macro, we could assume Windows and then UTF-16, but that's just one reasonable assumption.

Comment: @MSalters: tnx for the clarification.